# Jupyter notebook and Anaconda Navigator does not show after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

After installing Anaconda3 I tried to search in my start menu for Anaconda Navigator but it just doesn't show. All I get when typing Anaconda in my start menu is Anaconda Prompt, I have tried to launch jupyter notebook from the Anaconda Prompt but it says that "jupyter n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe", and it's the same for Anaconda Navigator.

I want to add that I select the case that add Anaconda to the Path and I have installed miniconda too and I didn't have any error message while installing.

Comment: Have you tried manually installing these packages from the anaconda command promt: `conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator` and `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter`?

Comment: I have just tried these commands but it gives me a ProxyError<'Cannot connect to proxy.' OSerror<'Tunnel connection failed:407 Proxy Authentification Requiered'>>

Comment: Then you probably need to configure your anaconda to use the proxy correctly. Mabe this will help: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#config-proxy

Comment: As I work for an enterprise I think I don't have the wright to change the proxy server. I'm working with windows 7 I don't have the access to LAN Settings.

Comment: The ideas is not to change the proxy server for your system or anything like that, but to add the proxy settings of your company to Anaconda

Comment: Can you please explain how? I don't see clear your idea

Comment: You should look up the proxy settings (can probably see them under ControlPanel->Network and Internet->Internet Options -> Connections->Lan Settings)

Comment: That's what I did but I don't have in my internet Options 'connections':

Comment: Okay, not knowing what the IT is like at your company I personally am not able to help you with the proxy issue I am afraid. But you can download the relevant packages manually from conda (just Google "conda + package name") and then install them using `conda install -c file:\\<path to package> - -override-channels`

Comment: For fixing the proxy issue I would recommend talking to your IT people about the neccessary settings. I am sure you are not the first one to use Anaconda in your company

Comment: Thank you, that's what I will do :)

Comment: Hey, I want to tell you that my essue was solved.

Comment: In fact I tried an old version of Anaconda exactly Anaconda3-4.0.1 and it works finally I have my Anaconda Navigator and can launch jupyter notebook.

Comment: So you just downloaded an older version and didn't have any issues?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In fact I didn't download it that's a collegue who gives it to me and I followed the same steps in the installlation, the same as I did with my first Anaconda's fist version (Anaconda3 5.0.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I was having the same issues after installing Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64 on Windows 10. Though my previous install of Python 3.6.5 was working quite well.
A possible workaround - which worked for me beautifully - is to uninstall the Anaconda3-5.2.0 and install an old version.

Try Anaconda3-4.0.1 as I did from https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

While installing just accept all the defaults.
Confirm that the Navigator is installed from the Start Menu or launch from command prompt with this command:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Once you are sure it is running - close and again from command prompt update to current version with:

```
conda update --all
```

Then:

```
conda update anaconda
```

You should now be good to go!

Answer (score 5):

i solved my problem by del .condarc file. And restart Navigator. That's ok.

Comment: Any further insight why it happens etc? if possible, please

Comment: Install fresh >> update packages caused this same error.  This solved it.  Thank you

Comment: Just to confirm: Solved it for me, too. I figure this is related to the order of the channels (default, cond-forge etc.) which is defined in `.condarc`.

Comment: deleting .condarc file worked for me also.
for me it was in c:users !!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to this in case people are looking way down the road. I ran into this issue using a company computer to install Anaconda Navigator and not seeing some of the normal applications on the Home Page of the Navigator including Jupyter Notebooks which was what I needed since my company seems to block any other method of installing and using an IDE for python.

What helped me was in the installer there was a recommended option to clear the cache after install. After trying a bunch of other things, I just instead ticked that 'off' and suddenly the install was good and I could find everything I needed. Simple I know.

Just hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried an old version of Anaconda exactly Anaconda3-4.0.1 and it works. Now I have my Anaconda Navigator and can launch jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also happened to me under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I solved my problem by changing my BASHRC file (~/.bashrc). 
In this file, there is one line added by Anaconda installer:
*export PATH="/home/mustafa1/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"  # commented out by conda initialize*
I just removed the # sign to make it work (of course I typed "source ~/.bashrc"), now I can see everything. I can use jupyter-notebook and anaconda-navigator.

Thus, my problem was a PATH issue. I think it is important where you install your anaconda.